# IIS WCF service with Basic Authentication and Custom UserNamePasswordValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

This is my Web.Config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-Requested-With,Content-Type, Accept" />
          </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <remove name="Remove service.svc" />
                <rule name="Remove service.scv">
                    <match url="^.+" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="service.svc/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel> 
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>  
    <services>      
      <service name="DTWebServiceLib.DTWebService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviourConf">  
            <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://x.x.x.x:81/webservice" />
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:81/webservice" />
            <add baseAddress="https://x.x.x.x:447/webservice" />
            <add baseAddress="https://localhost:447/webservice" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

        <endpoint address="/" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpointBinding" contract="DTWebServiceLib.IDTWebService" name="wsBasicEndpoint"/>

        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />

      </service>  
    </services>  
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>



    </bindings>
     <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviourConf">

            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False" httpsGetEnabled="True" />

            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />

            <serviceCredentials>
              <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="DTWebServiceLib.Security.CustomUserValidator, App_Code" />
              <serviceCertificate findValue="auth_cert" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
            </serviceCredentials>

        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>  
    <connectionStrings>
        <add connectionString="Server=***;Database=****;Integrated Security=true" name="Database" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />       
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>

      <customErrors mode="Off" />
        <compilation defaultLanguage="c#">
            <assemblies>
                <clear />
                <add assembly="mscorlib" />
                <add assembly="Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />

                <add assembly="*" />
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This is the custom class:

```
namespace DTWebServiceLib.Security
{
    class CustomUserValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
           ..    
        }
    }
}
```

When accessing the endpoint url through a browser, it just keeps asking for credentials, on a loop, and the custom class code is not executed.

I tried with this binding instead:

```
<binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
```

But then it just returns a 404 Error if it's accessed through the url in the browser. If I make an ajax request with the Authentication header then it starts the same credentials prompt loop.

I have enabled Basic authentication in IIS.

Am I doing something wrong in the configuration?

Thank you

Comment: Try this article http://www.cshandler.com/2015/10/basic-authentication-in-wcf-rest-on-iis.html

Comment: @vendettamit same problem...

Comment: Tried this as well: https://serverfault.com/questions/485006/why-cant-i-log-in-to-a-windows-protected-iis-7-5-directory-on-the-server/485011#485011 without luck